# Como imprimir un DIV sin perder los estilos de mi CSS

Tags: javascript, html, print

Quiero imprimir el contenido de un DIV, sin embargo el mismo pierde los estilos.
esta es la vista previa de la impresión, como pueden ver pierde todos los estilos :c ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este el código que tengo... [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien tiene algún código que funcione le agradecería mucho

Comment: Una imagen de tu codigo no es valido.
Te recomiendo revisar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de agregar estilos para impresión en tu archivo main.css

Ejemplo:
@media print {
  /* Aquí lo estilos que le quieras dar */
}

Comment: Puse los mismo estilos que ya tenia solo que esta ves dentro de otra hoja de estilos  usando ese @media print ... pero igual no me agrega los estilos